# Does 'calcul fastidieux' convey 'tedious calculations'? (i.e. lengthy ones)

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage, mathématiques

The question is obvious. Linguee has many examples where 'tedious calculations' is conveyed by 'calculs fastidieux'. But I don't recall to see or hear the French turn at all. Is it considered idiomatic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is the best word to translate "tedious". Other words could be "ennuyeux", "pénible", "déprimant", "poussif", ...